# php urlencode returns different results when run in a class

Tags: php

I'm running PHP 5.3.3 and when using `$str=urlencode("£")`, the value of `$str` is `%A3`, as I would expect. However if I call the `urlencode` function from within a class, the value of `$str` is `%C2%A3`.

I've also tried passing the £ through the function `http_build_query`, but this has the same variant in result when running outside / inside of a class. I can work around this using `str_replace` to rid `$str` of the unwanted encoding but would really like to know why this is happening. It's almost as though `urlencode` is using a different character set when being called from within a class.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you check the file encoding of your files ? (utf-8 / iso / ...) ?

Comment: The actual representation for "£" is "Â£" and the UTF-8 bites for this is `%C2%A3`. Checked it there : [UTF-8 Encoding Debugging Chart](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) About why the output is different in and outside the class, I don't know...

Comment: `%C2%A3` is UTF-8 and `%A3` is (probably) ISO 8859-1, so you have an encoding mismatch somewhere.

Comment: @AdrienLeber "The actual representation for `£` is `Â£`" is very very wrong. Better would be to say, if the sequence of bytes for `£` encoded in UTF-8 were displayed as ISO-8559-1, it appears as `Â£` and this is always a bug.

Comment: To the OP. Both are 'correct' urlencoded sequences. The shorter one is from ISO-8559-1, also know as latin1, the 2-byte one is from UTF-8. Your application _should_ be fully in UTF-8, so the longer byte sequence is more correct. `%C2%A3` is the output you should be going for.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sending data to a Progress Web Speed broker that uses ISO-8859-1 encoding, so I'm now using $str=urlencode(utf8_decode($str)); to do the encoding.

Answer (score -1):

There are very few reasons that `urlencode()` might return different values. Inside or outside the class is not the issue. We can rule that out very easily.

Create a file `test.php` with the following:

```
<?php
var_dump(urlencode("£"));
class x {
    public function y() {
        var_dump(urlencode("£"));
    }
}

$x = new X();
$x->y();
```

The above will print the exact same in both cases.

It's not an issue with PHP, or the function, or where you're using the function.

It looks like one value was stored UTF-8 and one was stored ISO 8859-1.

It's likely that the values are two different values of two different encodings. Check where the values come from, how they got there, and how they're being displayed. Are all the values using the same encodings e.g. UTF-8 or ISO 8859-1. What encoding are they stored in. When they were stored did they come from the encoded source e.g. html page (was the page encoded with the same encoded as all the above).

Comment: Thanks Gerard, with your help I've managed to get my head around this. I use Notepad++ to edit my scripts and it turns out that the file I keep my classes in was encoded in UTF-8, whereas the file that calls the classes was encoded as ANSI. Throughout my testing, the £ symbol was coded into each of these pages - hence the differing results!